# Given the following definition of a square matrix A, find the determinant for all sizes of the matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an $n \times n$ sized matrix, defined by $A_{ij}=\frac{1}{min(i,j)}$ find the determinant of A. I created an example 4 by 4 matrix and tried subtracting the first row from all the rows below it. This gave me a 1 followed by a bunch of zeros in the first column of the matrix. I then tried to use cofactor expansion since there was only a single 1 in the first column. But then I didn't know how to prove the determinant from there. (I would write out what I mean but I can't get the LaTex to format correctly in this text box sorry).

Comment: As a hint, you can prove by induction that $$\det(A) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!n!}.$$ Once you have established this for a particular $n$, then the case for $n+1$ follows by performing a certain elementary row operation on the $(n+1)$th row and then applying the cofactor expansion along that row.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead subtracting the second to last row from the last row. The row is then all 0s except for a 1 at the end. And because the other rows are unchanged, the cofactor expansion tells you the determinant is the same as for the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ version of the matrix. By induction, this tells you the determinant is $1$.